# git how to undo Merge branch 'master' of repo into develop branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I was working with the develop branch and made the commit.

And then, I was supposed to do a  `git pull origin develop` - instead I accidentally did this `git pull origin master`

Then, I saw this message `Merge branch 'master' of repo into develop branch`

Is there anyway I can undo this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the merge commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

and pull again

```
git pull origin develop
```

PS: I assume that your `develop` branch actual points to the merge commit.

**EDIT**

> if I do this, would I loose the commit made in develop branch ? No, right ?

The commit will not be referenced anymore, but it is still there. Git will Keep unreachable commits for a while. The default is 90 days. See [git gc](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

> The optional configuration variable gc.reflogExpire can be set to indicate how long historical entries within each branch’s reflog should remain available in this repository. The setting is expressed as a length of time, for example 90 days or 3 months. **It defaults to 90 days**.

So within this period you can restore the commit, but you must know it's id. You find the id in the [reflog](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) if it is not expired yet or just save it somewhere.

If you don't feel fine with this you can just create a local branch that points to the actual commit of your `develop` branch before doing a `git reset --hard`. In this case the local backup branch will reference the commit and git gc will not delete it (because it is referenced). E.g.

```
git branch backup/develop
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

If you think now: "Oh no I want to go back". Just do

```
git reset --hard backup/develop
```

otherwise delete the local backup branch

```
git branch -D backup/develop
```

Comment: if I do this, would I loose the commit made in develop branch ? No, right ?